# Ipad: when using swipe event the entire page is moving

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I have a book like application and the user can flip "pages" by swiping, problem is that when the user swipes a page the entire viewport is moving, is there a way to prevent it?

**HTML Excerpt:**

```
    <div data-title="Strategy" data-role="page" role="main" tabindex="0" class="ui-page ui-body-c ui-page-active" style="min-height: 545px;">
  <div data-role="content" class="caspBookCon ui-content" role="main">

    <div class="caspBookWrapper">
      <div class="caspBookLeft" data-bind="event: { swiperight: prevPage },visible:true" style="display: block;">
<div data-title="Home" role="main" data-cafevm="sp/book/strategy">
  <!-- ko if: isEditable() -->
  <a href="#" class="caspEdit" data-bind="visible: !editMode(), click:setEditMode" title="Edit"></a>
  <!-- /ko -->
  <div class="caspBtnGrayOverlay" data-bind="visible: editMode()" style="display: none;">
    <a href="#" class="caspButton caspBtnGray" data-bind="click:saveEdit">Done</a>
  </div>
```

**JS:**

```
/**
         * Move to next page.
         * @param  {[type]} d [description]
         * @param  {[type]} e [description]
         * @return {[type]}   [description]
         */
        var nextPage = function(d, e) {
            var chapter = ca.sp.book.currentChapter;

            if(chapter.isEnd()) {
                $.when(changeChapter(true)).then(function(chapter){
                    showPage(chapter);
                });
            } else {
                chapter.changePage(true);
                showPage(chapter);
            }
        };

        /**
         * Move to previous page
         * @param  {[type]} d [description]
         * @param  {[type]} e [description]
         * @return {[type]}   [description]
         */
        var prevPage = function(d, e) {
            var chapter = ca.sp.book.currentChapter;

            if(chapter.isStart()) {
                $.when(changeChapter(false)).then(function(chapter){
                    showPage(chapter);
                });
            } else {
                chapter.changePage(false);
                showPage(chapter);
            }
        };
```

Comment: Do you want to prevent horizontal + vertical scrolling?

Comment: Not scrolling.. when swiping i want the page to change but i don't want the entire viewport to move

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a little hacky, but you could try hooking into the `ontouchmove` event of the `<body>` tag and blocking it via jQuery, like this:

```
$("body").on({
    ontouchmove : function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Firstly, no need for jQuery there, and secondly, it's better to do it on `document`, rather than `body`.

Answer (score 1):

Just disable the `touchmove` event on the `document`:

```
document.touchmove = function(e)
{ 
    e.preventDefault(); 
};
```

Comment: Actually what worked for me was a combination of both yours and @AlistairFindlay answers: `$(document).on('touchmove', function(e)
  {
      e.preventDefault();
  });`
Not sure why your answer didn't work as it is, but i'll mark it as true anyway

Comment: Sorry, i just found out that this also prevents scrolling, so it is not a good enough solution, but you do get a +1 :)

Comment: Sorry, I guess I misunderstood your question.